# How to watch network traffic? A la packet sniffing or web debugging proxy?

Tags: http, proxy, debugging, traffic

So when I am debugging my web applications and such, I've used the Charles web proxy and debugger and love it. It's so nice to see what's being sent and received via port 80 and 443. I can see all the resources loading, not just from the "browser" per say, but also flash applications. I can also see how the calls are being made, and it pretty easy to reconstruct them. It's a great debugging tool and I love it.

So I'm wondering two things:

First, I'm wondering is if there is something similar I can use to watch traffic that might be coming though on other ports. I guess some desktop applications will use the internet, but not necessarily via http / https requests. I remember looking at some security tools a few years ago - there are a lot of security tools out there, like kismet / etherCap, ethershark, etc - is there one that does what I'm describing in an easy and intuitive way?

<del>Also, I'm wondering if I am using my iPhone / iPad / Android device, how can I set up a proxy through my computer so I can watch the http/https requests that the device makes?</del>

Found the answer to that one here: http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/ipad-http-debugging/

I'm mostly on a Mac so anything that is Mac friendly would be extra helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  It allows you to monitor the network interface on your machine and be able to tell you sent/receive packets as well as their protocols.  It also has a protocol decoder that can be used to get Layer 7 information about a IP stream.  You can also do a "Follow TCP stream" which allows you to view the entire conversation of that connection.  It's based on libpcap (Packet capture) which the built in tcpdump also uses.

The only downside for you web developers is that if you're using SSL encrypted sessions, you can't decode it.  The endpoints of the SSL session are "above" (using OSI model) the layer at which wireshark (and similar tools) operate.

Comment: Would it be worth setting up a Man-In-The-Middle type of proxy to be able to see SSL data? Know of any tools for doing that? Or perhaps I would do that and then use Wireshark? This actually is for web development purposes :)

Comment: For that you should be able to use [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/?page=index).  It will encrypt/decrypt the tunnel and then do something else with it.  You'd probably want encrypt from the client to the webserver and then translate the connection to the unencrypted port then you could use wireshark on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good list http://sectools.org/sniffers.html.  I used Wireshark back when it was Ethereal.  At that time it ran under X11, It looks like that has changed.